# Get notified when an entity state changes

Tags: mysql, winforms, entity-framework

I'm building an application which uses Entity Framework (version 6) to manage the persistance.  Its all new to me but I am pretty impressed with it so far.

I have a problem which I can't seem to find an answer for online due to being swamped by unrelated answers.  Basically I have forms which display the details of entities to the user for editing.  What I would like to do is have a Save Changes button which is enabled and disabled depending on the state of the entity (or DbEntityEntry more precisely).

I can determine the state of the entity from the Context so determining the state is not a problem.  Its knowing when the state changes that I'm having trouble with.  So an entity can be loaded from the data store and presented and initially will be in the unchanged state.  As soon as the user starts editing the form data the entity will become modified (due to data binding).

Where should I hook up to be notified of the change to the entity?  Should I hook into every control's changed event or the binding source changed event or other?

Details:
Entity Framework 6, WinForms, MySql Datastore

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your entity class like that:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

so class needs to be public and all properties needs to be virtual, public (at least protected) along with their setters and getters then when DbContext will instantiate this entity class for you it will instatiate it as an instance of class deriving from your entity class. This class implements interface IEntityWithChangeTracker. So all you have to do when you have your Person entity class and you want to track changes in it is to prepare class that implements IEntityChangeTracker interface like this:

```
public class PersonTracker : IEntityChangeTracker
{
    public void EntityComplexMemberChanged(string entityMemberName, object complexObject, string complexObjectMemberName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void EntityComplexMemberChanging(string entityMemberName, object complexObject, string complexObjectMemberName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void EntityMemberChanged(string entityMemberName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void EntityMemberChanging(string entityMemberName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.EntityState EntityState
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to provide implementation for those methods. Then you might use the following code to test it:

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext("Test"))
{
    Person p = context.People.First();
    (p as IEntityWithChangeTracker).SetChangeTracker(new PersonTracker());
            //After that line EntityTracker will be called
    p.SomeProperty = "new value";
}
```

If you want to track newly created entities that were not fetched from db do not instantiate them with new but instead use Create method:

```
Person p = context.People.Create();
```

Comment: You mean "instantiate them with new"? Then I wouldn't agree with you - Create() method as well calls constructor. But we might call Constructor either by using new or Create() and this is the difference.

Comment: Does setting the change tracker interfere with the tracking done by the context?  I.e. can I have my own tracking and allow the context to do it's own tracking as well?  Or does setting a custom tracker remove the context's tracker?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it does remove ef tracker. It won't work but still ef will recognize the changes you've done just before saving them to db. Other option for tracking entities that I see would be only implementing your own mechanism for that like with use of INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: On the other hand you might restore ef Tracker by calling context.People.Attach(p)

Comment: I think its worse than that.  Looking at the implementation in the source, EntityObject.SetChangeTracker (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/DataClasses/EntityObject.cs) throws an exception if you try to change the ChangeTracker.

Comment: But in newer versions entities classes do not derive from EntityObject any more - they are plain POCO objects. The code that I presented in answer was tested by me in ef 6.1 and it worked.

Comment: Oh right, I wondered how that worked.  It was the only implementation of that method I could find in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I considered using IEntityWithChangeTracker interface to track the changes to the entities.  In the end I didn't like the way that it would remove the context's ability to monitor changes  and adding the context's tracker back seemed to lose a lot of functionality.

So I eventually got my head around the Code First approach to EF (was previously working from a DB First workflow).  This gave me more flexibility in customising the entity classes.

So I implemented the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface using an entity base class and triggered the event in each property's setter.  Its worth looking at the MS implementation in the link above as it uses an optional property name argument so that you can call it without having to specify the property name (in a string, yuck).

You can also override the property name with a string in case updating one property affects the value of another property (eg update FirstName changes readonly property FullName).  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) for more details.

```
Public MustInherit Class EntityBase
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

End Class
```